# On Ubuntu and in tmux, vim does not react to Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, linux, tmux, cursor

Outside of tmux they work well. These key combinations should move the cursor to the beginning of the document and, respectively, to the end of the document.

How do I make them work?

Thank you very much! `:-)`

Comment: Not an answer, but: why not just use `G` and `gg`?

Comment: @silviubogan If they work well outside of tmux it probably means tmux is intercepting your keystrokes, you could look at `~/.tmux.conf` and see if maybe you have defined some mappings for `<C-Home>` and `<C-End>` there.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Ctrl-Home and Ctrl-End don't work for Vim inside of Tmux is because Tmux eats those inputs.

To fix this you need to unbind the affected keys in your Tmux config wich is located at `~/.tmux.conf`

To unbind a key
`unbind-key -[key]`

So for your example:
`unbind-key C-Home`
`unbind-key C-End`

Comment: There is [no indication](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/2.5/tmux.1) that `tmux` had anything bound to those keys. And they're not bound these days. And by the way, doesn't `unbind-key C-Home` unbinds `C-b C-Home`, not `C-Home`?